# Why class that implements a interface is not an instance of that interface?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I want to do dependency injection like this

```
<?php
    class UserModel
    {
        public function __construct(DatabaseInterface $db)
        {
            $this->db = $db;
        }
    }
```

So I have created the Database class and an interface for it

```
<?php
    interface DatabaseInterface {}

    class PdoConnection implements DatabaseInterface
    {
        ...
```

But when I try to make instance of UserModel passing an instance of PdoConnection I get an error

```
$user = new UserModel(new \Manager\Database\PdoConnection);

__construct() must be an instance of DatabaseInterface, instance of Manager\Database\PdoConnection given
```

I am not sure why since the PdoConnection implements DatabaseInterface so I believe UserModel should just accept it?

Debugging below

```
$class = new \Manager\Database\PdoConnection();
if ($class instanceof DatabaseInterface) {
    echo "variable class is a instance of DatabaseInterface";
} else {
    echo "variable class is not a instance of DatabaseInterface";
}

var_dump(class_implements($class));
```

Results

```
variable class is not a instance of DatabaseInterface

array(1) {
  'Manager\Database\DatabaseInterface' =>
  string(34) "Manager\Database\DatabaseInterface"
}
```

Comment: I guess you need to write `Manager\Database\DatabaseInterface` everywhere instead of simply `DatabaseInterface`.

Comment: @Adder that works, thanks! I forgot to import the interface with the "use". Feel free to post an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write `Manager\Database\DatabaseInterface` everywhere instead of simply `DatabaseInterface`.